# javascript odometer restarts at zero with postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two javascript odometers that are used to display cyclists mileages as miles YTD, and # of centuries. They should update only when the cyclist adds miles to their log, however, at this time they are going back to zero and rolling up to the same total with every pageback. This is the js on the design (aspx) page

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Get the value from serverside
        var uid = '<%=odometermilesvalue %>';
        odometermiles.innerHTML = uid;
    }, 1000)

    setTimeout(function () {
        //Get the value from serverside
        var uid = '<%=odometermilesvalue1 %>';
        odometer1.innerHTML = uid;
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

Then, in the body the odometers are displayed:

```
 <div id="odometer" class="odometer"></div>
 <div id="odometer" class="odometer"></div>
```

The code behind retrieves the mileages from SQL and assigns that value to a variable that is passed to   the aspx. I can see that the values will be updated too often, since the code that pulls from SQL is in the page load event, but I don't know how to fix it. If anyone has experience with this please give me a clue or  two.

1. How do you initialize the odometer on open to the current mileage?
2. Should I be using an update panel? and if so do I use one for each odometer?

Comment: You can't have duplicate `id="odometer"`.

Comment: Aswell as fix the id's, try setting the initial text inside the odometers to 0.00 or similar

Comment: You can't have duplicate id="odometer - Actually, I don't, they are odometer & odom1